htaccess regex redirection mantaining url structure
Im trying to do a redirection from domain/web/something to sub.domain/web/something, and only for /web/ but this code is redirecting all website

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.es\web\$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.es/web/$1 [R=301,L]

# https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.\web\es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.es/web/$1 [R=301,L]


Ive tried the code above expecting to redirect some url group to another but what im getting is full website redirected instead

The reason the redirect with /web# may not be working is because of how browsers handle URL fragments, also known as "anchors" (the part of the URL after the #).
When a browser makes a request to a server, it does not include the URL fragment in the request. This means that the server is not aware of the # part of the URL, and therefore cannot redirect based on it.
In other words, if you have a URL like domain.es/web#section1, just the server and domain.es/web in the request. The #section1 fragment is handled entirely by the browser and is not sent to the server.
Therefore, you cannot do a redirect based on the URL fragment using .htaccess or any other server-side configuration. You would need to handle this on the client side, possibly with JavaScript.
If you need to redirect based on the URL fragment, you might consider changing your URL scheme to use paths instead of fragments, for example, changing domain.es/web#section1 to domain.es/web/section1. This would allow the server to see and redirect based on the full part of the URL.
